# PHP and Twig Set Variable Value

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am working with CI Framework and using Twiggy Template Engine for this. I am getting issue from last day and after do everything i couldn't found solution about how to override php array value using twig. Here is code and with this you can understand more..

```
$data['get_sup_sp_id'] = 6;
$data['profile'] = $this->user_model->get_sp_Profile($data['get_sup_sp_id']);
```

Twig Code :

```
{{ dump(data.profile) }}
```

Twig code just dump array values but i want to set according to id but not want to set static as i already.

Is there any solution in twig or twig filters with that i can set $data['get_sup_sp_id];

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can merge a hash (php associative array) into an existing hash like so:

```
{{ dump(data|merge({ 'get_sup_sp_id': 2 })) }}
```

See more on merging here: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/merge.html#merge

Comment: Thanks i did same but getting error : 

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Runtime' with message 'The merge filter only works with arrays or hashes in "main.html.twig" at line 61.' in

Comment: Not sure what exactly you´re trying to do, maybe you want to merge the value into the data array instead of into the data.profile? So that would be data|merge({ ... })

Comment: I want to update profile according to id using get_sp_Profile php function but this function have parameter and i am using framework so i can't write twig filter to get values. Final thing i want to override  $data['get_sup_sp_id'] = 6; using twig ex: {{ data.get_sup_sp_id = 2 }}

Comment: I updated my answer with a solution to how to change the get_sup_sp_id value. however, the change to the array will likely run after the call to your user_model, so this will not change the profile data.

Comment: Thanks it's worked but showing lots of data because of dump and when i use without dump it just shows array.

Comment: Sure, if you just want to set the key, dont use the dump method. also if you dont want output, use {% ... %}